# Google Chrome won't open .URL extension files Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, displaylink, url, elinks

I recently tried to open a URL link I saved onto my desktop by double-clicking it, but it will not open correctly. If I DRAG & DROP the file into chrome works fine.
The file is saved with a **".url" extension.**

Comment: Just to let you know: 14.04 is unsupported and considered off topic

Comment: Your Ubuntu version is no longer supported. You better update it! Your question can be closed because it is off-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See if this works first

This is a known issue with Google Chrome. See:[Chrome doesn't recognise .url files properly](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114871&can=5&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)

The workaround is to use an Extension such as [.URL Handler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-handler/nhmccpjmdhejpfhafcfajkgifkmjhkgf)

Once installed you need to go to Chrome Extensions (chrome://extensions/) and turn on Allow access to file URLs toggle.

### If it doesn't try this

1. Paste this in terminal and press enter: `ln -s /opt/google/chrome/chrome /usr/bin/chrome`
2. Install thunar file manager: `sudo apt-get install thunar`
3. - Right-click a .URL file
   - Select: "Open With"
   - "Open With Other Application"
   - Select on "Use a custom command"
     [image: example]
4. Copy the following command to the text-field: `bash -c "cat %f | grep URL | cut -d'=' -f2 | xargs chrome &"`
5. Click the default checkbox.

[image: example.]

6. Press open.
7. You can uninstall thunar file manager: `sudo apt-get remove thunar`